# Android ActionBar Menu: why I'm getting an arrow instead of 3 dots?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm trying to have 3 dots instead of arrow on the top right of my Android App.
What I have right now is something like this:

[image]

And I want to have the 3 dots instead of the orrible arrow on TOP LEFT.
I'm trying it on Android 4.2+ devices, every device show me the arrow.

My XML for the menu is this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item 
    android:id="@+id/BD_Fav"
    android:title="Favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/iLikeMenu"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item 
    android:id="@+id/BD_Read"
    android:title="Read"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
```

....

What's wrong? Can it be a matter of style applied somewhere else? What do I have to check?

EDIT:

```
 <style name="FairActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/fairNav</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: which one you talking about the last element or anything else you only have two items in menu or more

Comment: post your style to check what are you using for toolbar/actionbar

Answer (score 1):

```
<item 
android:id="@+id/BD_Read"
android:title="Read"
android:showAsAction="never" />
```

I believe you should use "never" if you want always the 3 dots. You can also use "ifRoom" as you're using in the favorite item.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

> android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"

to

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

Also I highly recommend you to change your styling to one from AppCompat:

```
<style name="FairActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  ...
```

so your styling will be consistent on all android versions

Answer (score 0):

Possible Causes:

1. you are using old SDK, Build tools, 
   solution: build using latest sdk & build tools
2. the three dot menu is shown in 4.4+ devices, before that default menu was hardware button, you can force to view the three dot menu - it is called overflow menu

Answer (score 0):

just chnage ifRoom and collapsable to never as follows

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/BD_Fav"
    android:title="Favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/iLikeMenu"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item 
    android:id="@+id/BD_Read"
    android:title="Read"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
```